# Modify XML tags on "NodeJS"

Tags: xml, node.js

Does anyone know how to modify a tag value of an XML file using NodeJS

this is my XML file:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want to change the `<node>` to `<n>`

I'm running nodeJS on windows. SO far I have following code;

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
function xmltxt(response, postData){
    fs.readFile( './foo.xml', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            console.dir(result.note.to[0]);
        });
    });
}
```

This reads the node value but I need to modify the tag value.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using [damn-simple-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/damn-simple-xml) you can do the following:

```
var Serializer = require("damn-simple-xml");  // constructor
var dsx = new Serializer();
var fs = require("fs");

var out = fs.createWriteStream("./foo2.xml");

dsx.deserialize(fs.createReadStream("./foo.xml"), function(err, root) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    dsx.serialize({
        name: "n",
        data: root.data
    }, 
    function(err, xmlpart, level) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        out.write(xmlpart);
        if (level === 0) { // XML streaming done
            out.end(); // closes the stream.
        }
    });
});
```

In the previous example, we receive a `root` object in the deserialization callback. This object consist of `root.name` (i.e. the name of the root node) and `root.data` which is the actual data from the deserialized XML document.

Then when serializing, we give back the same `root.data` object but there we change the root node's name to "n" as specified in your question.

Since damn-simple-xml can use streams to input xml and outputs it's content as XML chunks, the library have a very small memory footprint.