# Load a XML file to cloudant by node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, parsing, cloudant, ibm-cloud

I'm in a Hackathon and we have to use IBM Bluemix technologies.
We are all new to NodeJs and IBM Bluemix.

We need to upload [this](http://www.dati.gov.it/catalog/dataset/lazio-innova_poi_culturali) XML (there are also TTL, RDF and N3 formats) in the way to create a db and upload everything into it.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: what kind of db will you be using?

Comment: Thanks @Yousef for your question, we are using Cloudant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example and code assume you are using Express 3.  Express 4 is a little different with body parsing...

1. Post the file to express.
2. Read in the uploaded file
3. Convert the XML to JSON.
4. Store the JSON in your DB.

   ```
   app.post("/upload", function (request, response) {
       async.waterfall(
           [
               function (next) {
                   //where leads is the name of the field from your html page
                   fs.readFile(request.files.leads.path, next);
               },
               function (xml, next) {
                   var json = parser.toJson(xml);
                   db.insert(json, next)
               },
           ], function (error) {
               if (error) {
                   console.log(error);
                   response.send(error);
                   return;
               }
               response.redirect("/");
           }
       );
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd :

1. Read in the XML file
2. Convert the XML model into a JSON object
3. Then use the [nano npm library](https://github.com/dscape/nano) to insert the data into Cloudant

Answer (score 0):

Try [damn-simple-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/damn-simple-xml) to convert to a JavaScript object. It's easy to use and there is a good example of a simple case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137120/modify-xml-tags-on-nodejs/29352064#29352064).

Comment: You shall skip the XML header line before passing the stream.Readable to damn-simple-xml `deserialize` function though...